# Cisco 1200 AP, client information from CLI

Tags: cisco, wireless, cisco-ios, cli, cisco-wireless

I'm working with several cisco 1200 series APs, trying to get relevant client information off of them.  It would be helpful to see RSSI and SNR for individual clients connected, but I am unable to find any commands that are related to this.  I've checked around the cisco forums, and a lot of people were able to find this info using some perl scripts along with information from end user wireless cards, but that is not an option for me.  I have remote access only to the APs.  Other posts recommend using some kind of wireless controller to view this, but that is also not an option.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You state that using a Wireless Controller is out of the question, are these "Autonomous" Access Points?  That is to say, is there no Wireless Controller in your environment, or you don't have access to the Controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*You state that a Wireless Controller is not an option, so I'm assuming these are Autonomous Access Points.*

On Cisco Autonomous APs, you are looking for the `show dot11 associations` command and it's associated sub commands.

It gives an output like so:

```
SPARKY#show dot11 associations                                  

802.11 Client Stations on Dot11Radio0: 

SSID [sparky] : 

MAC Address    IP address      IPV6 address     Device        Name     Parent         State 
XXXX.da1d.1b05 172.20.1.102    ::               unknown       -        self           Assoc
XXXX.2c90.c42f 172.20.1.103    ::               unknown       -        self           Assoc
XXXX.59c0.4ac4 172.20.1.116    ::               unknown       -        self           Assoc
```

Once you have the MAC address of your client, you can run the `show dot11 associations <MAC ADDRESS>` command where `<MAC ADDRESS>` is the MAC address of the client you're interested in.  It should give you all the information you're after.  You can also run `show dot11 associations all-client` and see this information for all associated clients.  See the below sample:

```
SPARKY#show dot11 associations XXXX.da1d.1b05
Address           : XXXX.da1d.1b05     Name             : NONE
IP Address        : 172.20.1.102       IPv6 Address        : ::                                      
Gateway Address   : 0.0.0.0            
Netmask Address   : 0.0.0.0            Interface        : Dot11Radio 0
Bridge-group        : 1
reap_flags_1        : 0x0     ip_learn_type       : 0x0       transient_static_ip : 0x0       
Device            : unknown            Software Version : NONE 
CCX Version       : NONE               Client MFP       : Off

State             : Assoc              Parent           : self               
SSID              : sparky                          
VLAN              : 10
Hops to Infra     : 1                  Association Id   : 3
Clients Associated: 0                  Repeaters associated: 0
Tunnel Address    : 0.0.0.0
Key Mgmt type     : WPAv2 PSK          Encryption       : AES-CCMP
Current Rate      : m7-2               Capability       : WMM ShortHdr ShortSlot
Supported Rates   : 1.0 2.0 5.5 11.0 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0 m0-2 m1-2 m2-2 m3-2 m4-2 m5-2 m6-2 m7-2
Voice Rates       : disabled           Bandwidth        : 20 MHz 
Signal Strength   : -59  dBm           Connected for    : 209172 seconds
Signal to Noise   : 34  dB            Activity Timeout : 25 seconds
Power-save        : Off                Last Activity    : 35 seconds ago
Apsd DE AC(s)     : NONE

Packets Input     : 8306               Packets Output   : 4109      
Bytes Input       : 816594             Bytes Output     : 565535    
Duplicates Rcvd   : 17                 Data Retries     : 803       
Decrypt Failed    : 0                  RTS Retries      : 0         
MIC Failed        : 0                  MIC Missing      : 0         
Packets Redirected: 0                  Redirect Filtered: 0         
IP source guard failed : 0             PPPoE passthrough failed : 0             
DAI failed : IP mismatch  : 0             src MAC mismatch : 0             target MAC mismatch : 0           
Existing IP failed :  0              New IP failed :  0             
11w Status       : Off
Session timeout   : 0 seconds
Reauthenticate in : never
```

Comment: Yes they are all autonomous, there is no controller installed at the site.  And thanks, these are exactly the commands I was looking for.  Seriously, you just saved myself and co-workers a lot of headache